# xcode horizontal table like app store

Tags: xcode, tableview, horizontal-scrolling

I have attempted to create a table within a table cell to present similarly of the horizontal table cell slide like that of the app store.

If you go into the app store and click the featured products tab you will see what i mean.

A nested horizontal slide table.

I have downloaded one that works vey well from the internet but it seems to use nibs. I am looking to create one using the storyboard feature. My reasoning for this is that i find it easy to use especially when doing segues etc

I have come so far in having one complete but i cannot seem to resize the cells to fit properly (i.e., the cells width is the height of the rotated table)

here is some of my code copied from a downloaded source

the table

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {

       CGAffineTransform rotateTable = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
       tableViewCell.horizontalTableView.transform = rotateTable;
       tableViewCell.horizontalTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableViewCell.horizontalTableView.frame.size.width, tableViewCell.horizontalTableView.frame.size.height);

      tableViewCell.contentArray = [arrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

      tableViewCell.horizontalTableView.allowsSelection = YES;
      //cell = tableViewCell.horizontalTableView;

     }

    return cell;
}
```

the table cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.horizontalTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
   }

   for (UIImageView *view in cell.subviews) {
       [view removeFromSuperview];
   }

   CGAffineTransform rotateTable = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
   horizontalTableView.transform = rotateTable;
   horizontalTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, horizontalTableView.frame.size.width, horizontalTableView.frame.size.height);

   tableViewCell.contentArray = [arrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

   horizontalTableView.allowsSelection = YES;

   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
   imageView.image = [contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

   CGAffineTransform rotateImage = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
   imageView.transform = rotateImage;

   [cell addSubview:imageView];

   return cell;
}
```

Allow me to explain the problems incurred:
- cell==nil does not work as cell does not seem to be nil;
- cell = tableViewCell.horizontalTableView is commented out because i always get UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath error
- the cell rotation seems to work as i have it in the table cell section but this seems to be where the problem is as i have cannot resize it

If someone could help me with my code or point me to a site that has a working storyboard nested horizontal table it would be greatly appreciated.

(bear in mind i am yet to be called a professional in app development but i am stretching the boundaries trying to pull this off)